# Cannot set object value with merge value

Tags: php, object, foreach

I have a a problem with my loop. When I `print_r($item);` on key 'text' value only show `$item->NamaUnor` value, not `$item->NamaPim` too. This is my code:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $item->text=&$item->NamaUnor.' '.$item->NamaPim;
    $item->href=&$item->KdUnor;

    $childs[$item->UnorAtasan][] = $item;

    unset($item->NamaPim,$item->NamaUnor,$item->UnorAtasan);
}
```

Comment: May be the NamaPim value is empty. Show us the $items.

Comment: why are you using the reference? `=&` it is completely unnecessary..

Comment: $item->NamaPim  value not empty. I was try to set 

$item->text=&$item->NamaUnor.' '.$item->NamaPim;

be

$item->text=&$item->NamaUnor.' blabalbal';

but still not working.

i want to make tree hierarki

Comment: Try it without the reference.. `$item->text=$item->NamaUnor.' '.$item->NamaPim`

Comment: still not working guys

Comment: `var_dump($item->text);` and verify the presence of the space at the end.  If it is present, then your problem is not in this code, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all i was fix it with add & before $item to foreach on my code.

```
foreach($items as **&$item**){
$item->text=&$item->NamaUnor.' '.$item->NamaPim;
$item->href=&$item->KdUnor;

$childs[$item->UnorAtasan][] = $item;

unset($item->NamaPim,$item->NamaUnor,$item->UnorAtasan);
```

}